# Im having an error on this program

Tags: c#

on the lines that i have "using System;", "using System.IO", and "namespace BinaryFileApplication". so i really don't know what to do with them to make C program recognize them.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace BinaryFileApplication
{

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BinaryWriter bw;
        BinaryReader br;
        int i = 25;
        double d = 3.14157;
        bool b = true;
        string s = "I am happy";

        //create the file
        try
        {
            bw = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream("mydata", FileMode.Create));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message + "\n Cannot create file.");
            return;
        }

        //writing into the file
        try
        {
            bw.Write(i);
            bw.Write(d);
            bw.Write(b);
            bw.Write(s);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message + "\n Cannot write to file.");
            return;
        }

        bw.Close();

        //reading from the file
        try
        {
            br = new BinaryReader(new FileStream("mydata", FileMode.Open));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message + "\n Cannot open file.");
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            i = br.ReadInt32();
            Console.WriteLine("Integer data: {0}", i);
            d = br.ReadDouble();
            Console.WriteLine("Double data: {0}", d);
            b = br.ReadBoolean();
            Console.WriteLine("Boolean data: {0}", b);
            s = br.ReadString();
            Console.WriteLine("String data: {0}", s);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message + "\n Cannot read from file.");
            return;
        }

        br.Close();

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: A C compiler *won't* recognize them - you can't just compile C# code as C.  You'll have to actually translate this to C code.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, please add proper tags so others can helps you.

Comment: Alternately, you need to use a *C#* compiler to build it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  This looks like .Net code.  Why would expect a "C" compiler to understand it?

Answer (score 0):

This code isn't C - it's C#.  You will have to build it with a *C#* compiler (either within Visual Studio, or using Mono, or something like that).

If you *really* want to build it *as C*, you will have to convert it to legal C code.  A close equivalent would be the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  FILE *bw, *br;
  int i = 25;
  double d = 3.14157;
  _Bool b = true;
  char s[] = "I am happy";

  bw = fopen( "mydata", "wb" );
  if ( bw )
  {
    if ( fwrite( &i, sizeof i, 1, bw ) != sizeof i )
      // error writing i;
    if ( fwrite( &d, sizeof d, 1, bw ) != sizeof d )
      // error writing d
    if ( fwrite( &b, sizeof b, 1, bw ) != sizeof b )
      // error writing b
    if ( fwrite( s, sizeof s, 1, bw ) != sizeof s ) // no & operator on s
      // error writing s
    fclose( bw );
  }

  // remainder left as exercise
}
```

C doesn't have namespaces<sup>1</sup>, it doesn't have classes, it doesn't have `BinaryReader` or `BinaryWriter`, it doesn't do structured exception handling, etc.  It's a *completely different language* from C#.

---

1. That is, it doesn't have *user-definable* namespaces.  There are
   4 built-in namespaces: label names, struct and union tag names, struct and union member names, and everything else.